# Import Yahoo! Mail and contacts to Gmail without Y! Mail Plus

Tags: gmail, yahoo-mail, import

I don't have Yahoo! Mail Plus so when [I tried to import from Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8088/gmail-import-problems-migrating-from-yahoo-mail-plus) as someone else has it doesn't work for me and I get migration errors.

Only a month's worth of email is imported after I tried to reimport mails. Previously new mails are not fetched.

How can I import it now?

Answer (score 1):

Get all mail from Yahoo via POP/IMAP, then put it to Gmail via IMAP.

Comment: I used Thunderbird for that, works great.

Comment: we need to pay for POP na

Answer (score 1):

You can now POP YMail into Gmail on non-paid accounts.

["Migrate to Gmail from Hotmail, Yahoo Mail, AOL Mail"](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/05/migrate-from-hotmail-yahoo-mail-aol.html) works.

Answer (score 0):

[Mozilla Thunderbird 3.1](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) works perfectly and is very general. Simply add the 2 email accounts to Thunderbird and move folders and email messages from one account to another. Setting up the email accounts is very simple as Thunderbird recognizes both Yahoo! and Gmail and sets up the correct IMAP settings.
The contacts can be copied directly by exporting from one email provider to a CSV file and then importing to the other email provider.
Hat tip to [KeithR](http://74.125.71.132/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=766e46d65c583bd0&hl=en).