# How to push Yahoo Small Business email to Gmail

Tags: gmail, yahoo, synchronization, pop3

How can I setup a push synchronization between my Yahoo Small Business account and my Gmail account? I would like Gmail to update my Yahoo inbox in real-time.

I have the accounts set up, but Gmail is still only pulling, no pushing of changes back to Yahoo.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a forward in your Yahoo email account. This way as soon as the email arrives in your Yahoo mailbox it will be immediately forwarded to Gmail.

Then, you can setup **send email as** under *Gmail settings -> Accounts and Import* so you can send all your emails from whichever account you want directly from Gmail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid that won't do either. From the Small Biz Help: "Email forwarding allows you to receive any messages sent to your Business Email account at a different email address. **New email will not appear in your Business Email account.**" Sigh why is this so difficult. Curse you Yahoo...

Comment: @rabbid This is only a problem if you will be using your Yahoo email "console". If you set it up properly you never have to login to your Yahoo email account since everything will be accessible from within Gmail and therefore not having new emails there shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: I suppose that is true. I'll give it some thought. Meanwhile, I'm still baffled why push email is not working. Sigh... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @rabbid Push can only be set up on the Yahoo! side, not the Gmail side. That's what email forwarding is.

Answer (score 0):

[Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) is very useful for importing mail between different services. You can set up a filter to move or copy email from one account to the inbox of the other account.

See also [Import Yahoo! Mail and contacts to Gmail without Y! Mail Plus](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8087/import-yahoo-mail-and-contacts-to-gmail-without-y-mail-plus/9348#9348)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I asked at all. I am not trying to import mail between Ymail and Gmail. I am simply trying to view all my emails in one place, Gmail. I have accomplished that task, however Gmail is not updating my Yahoo inbox in real-time, or using "push." It is checking for mail every X minutes, or "pull." How do I get it to "push" ? Thanks.