# Downloading all my Yahoo! Mail to my desktop computer

Tags: yahoo-mail, download

I've a free Yahoo! Mail account nearing 300 emails and I want to download the mail to my computer. I also have a backup of the emails in a Gmail account.

Is there something in Yahoo! Mail that will help me download all my email?

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo supports POP with a [paid account](http://overview.mail.yahoo.com/enhancements/mailplus) (and as of December 2013, with standard accounts as well). Gmail supports POP and IMAP - set up a mail client like [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) according to the instructions provided by the mail provider and that's about it.

Thunderbird should save by default. To be sure, go to **Tools** -> **Account Settings** -> **Synchronization & storage**, and ensure **Keep messages for this account on the computer** is ticked for that account
[image]

Comment: can you please describe the steps for downloading the mail, coz last time i installed **thunderbird** and was also able to view the mail, but there was no option to save it to the disk !

Comment: Edited answer, with instructions and screenshot

Comment: @Sourav: Drag and drop the messages -- to "Local folders", to Gmail, or even to your desktop.

Comment: I didn't know about the drag and drop bit - and .eml files seem to be plain text.. neat!

Comment: Thunderbird recognizes Yahoo! (as well as Gmailm etc.) and sets up the correct IMAP settings automatically. See also [Import Yahoo! Mail and contacts to Gmail without Y! Mail Plus](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8087/import-yahoo-mail-and-contacts-to-gmail-without-y-mail-plus). Note also that you set more than one email account on Thunderbird and set up a filter to move or copy new incoming emails to another account.